# Strong Lyapunov function for dissipative system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider the Liénard equation:
$$u''+f(u, u')u'+g(u)=0$$
where $f, g$ are continuously differentiable, $f$ is definite positive and $g$ satisfies $ug(u)>0$ if $u\neq 0$. I want to find a strong Lyapunov function for this system, or rather its equivalent 2d system:

$$u_1' = u_2,\;\;\;\;\; u_2' = -u_2f+g$$

I have tried many functions, but they all seem to fail the $V'<0$ condition. For example, if one takes the $H = \dfrac{u_2^2}{2}+\displaystyle\int_0^{u_1}g$ as the Lyapunov function, then $H' = -u_2^2f$, which vanishes at $u_2=0$, even if $u_1\neq 0$.

Another function I tried was $V = H+\beta u_2g$, where $\beta$ is a sufficiently small constant that makes $V$ definite positive. In this case, $V' = (\beta g'-f)u_2^2-\beta u_2fg-\beta g^2$, but I don't know if this is indeed negative definite.

Comment: For Lyapunov functions, the condition on the derivative is that it is negative definite; i.e. $V'(x)<0$ for all $x\ne 0$. Do you have $g(0)=0$ as well? From what I am reading, you are looking for a Lyapunov function for an equilibrium point at the origin.

Comment: $g(0)=0$ follows from the fact that $ug(u)>0$ for $u\neq 0$ and that $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline. I leave the details to you. Using the inequality $2|ab|\leq \frac{a^2}{\delta}+\delta b^2$, expand the term $-\beta u_2 f g\leq \beta f |u_2 g|$. You get an expression of the form $$V'\leq-f u_2^2(1-\beta(  g'/f +\delta/2))-\beta(1-f/(2\delta))g^2$$ Restrict $u_1,u_2$ in a compact set to get bounds on $g'$ and $f$, and select the constants $\delta$, $\beta$ appropriately. Eventually you get some local results.

Edit: Unfortunately, this works only with $f>0$ for all $u_1,u_2$.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't think this totally solves the problem. If we take $f=u_1^2 + u_2^2$ and $g=u_1$, then evaluating at $u_1=0$ gives us the inequality $V'\leq -u_2^4 \left(1-\beta \left( \dfrac{1}{u_2^2}+\dfrac{\delta}{2} \right)\right)$ (I think you misplaced a parenthesis in your inequality). We need $ 1 > \beta\left(\dfrac{1}{u_2^2}+\dfrac{\delta}{2}\right)$, but for $u_2$ sufficiently small this doesn't hold.

Comment: Indeed, missed the parenthesis. You need to restrict $u_1$ and $u_2$ in a compact set. Say for instance $|u_1|\leq k_1$ and $|u_2|\leq k_2$. Then, since $f$ and $g'$ are $C^1$, they are bounded, say $A=max(|g'|)$ in the compact set and $B=min(f)$. Then, $V'\leq -B u_2^2(1-\beta(A/B+\delta/2)-\beta(1-max(f)/(2\delta))g^2$. You take $\delta $ sufficiently big and $\beta$ sufficiently small.

Comment: That would work if $f$ was positive in a neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$, but according to the conditions of the problem, it could happen that $f(0, 0) = 0$ (definite positive only means $f(u_1, u_2)>0$ if $(u_1, u_2)\neq (0, 0)$), in this case $B=0$.

Comment: Oh I missed that